# Angularjs setting filter variable dynamically via infoWindow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, angularjs-ng-click

I have a select box that interact with the angular list and it works fine. The select box handle the 'citta' field and when I change the value of it, the list is filtered.

```
ng-model="queryLoc.citta"
```

Before everything, I istantiate the variable

```
$scope.queryLoc = { citta: ''};
```

Now I want to set the queryLoc value from a click of a button inside an infoWindow of google maps. When I click the button, I call the function 'filtraLoc'using this code

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('eventCont')).scope().filtraLoc(citta);
```

this is what the function filtraLoc is doing.

```
$scope.filtraLoc = function(city){
    $scope.queryLoc = {citta: city};
};
```

In my json I have the attribute 'citta' as you can see

```
{   
    immagine:'/upload/cms/770_x/Lonato(2).jpg',
    linkScheda: '/cms-01.00/articolo.asp?IDcms=77193&s=269',
    nome: 'MERCATO CONTADINO A LONATO DEL GARDA',
    citta: 'Lonato del Garda',
    data: 'OGNI SABATO MATTINA DALLE ORE 8 ALLE 13',
    categoria: '', 
    latitudine: '8', 
    longitudine: '82', 
    show: 'false'
}
```

but the filter doesn't work! I'm running out of ideas also because the console of the browser, doesn't give me any errors.

Thank you for any help or tips that you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

just need to use the $digest and transform the code from this:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('eventCont')).scope().filtraLoc(citta);
```

to this:

```
var tmp = angular.element(document.getElementById('eventCont'));
tmp.scope().queryLoc  = {citta: city};
tmp.scope().$digest();
```